Change the icon or title of a .exe (Pycharm) at runtime
On Windows, I'm running the same Pycharm binary with two different sets of environment vars. I launch them using two different Powershell scripts, and I can make the shortcut icons visually distinct. But once Pycharm launches, they're visually identical.
I'd like to be able to keep straight which instance is which. My first thought was to somehow change the icon. But my understanding is that icons are stored within the binary or set by the application.
Is there any generally-applicable way to launch the same application in two different ways and have the resulting windows be visually-distinct on the taskbar or alt-tab screen, as though they were two "different" programs?
There are some workarounds I'm considering, like:

Copy-pasting the .exe and patching one of them. (Unfortunate since reinstalls or updates might break this, and also it might have unintended side effects)
Launching them with two different configs and making some obvious visual change to the theme of one. That doesn't let me immediately click on the correct one, but it does give me a good way to know if I'm currently looking at the wrong one.

But if there's a "correct" way to handle this I'd like to know about it.
